# I load a php script using Jquery and it loads a cached result. How to solve?

Tags: php, caching, mysqli, browser-cache

Essentially I am coding a website for a university. I have a script that allows researchers to add their profile to the departments database. These profiles need to be approved by an admin before being available on the public site.

In the admin panel, I have a page called researchers, that shows the admins all the researchers in the department in a table. There is another tab that shows the researchers that are awaiting approval.

The php script to show the table is loaded through JQuery. I clear the div using JQuery empty function, then load the php script using JQuery load function. The problem is when I load the script, it loads a cached version of the script. If I approve a researcher, and click the tab awaiting approval, the researcher that I just approved still shows up as awaiting approval, unless I clear the cache. Any ideas? Not sure what code to post to help get an answer.

Thanks

Comment: Have triied using on the php script to no avail....

   <head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
</head>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about add a timestamp to your get url. like `get/this/url.php?timestamp=2345232423`
This way it should not cache it.

Comment: Yeah pretty much need to add a random number at the end. Thank you